# how to get java xml parser last element when different depth

Tags: javaparser

```
I have xml file like
<Results>
   <ResultList>
      <ImageResultList>
           <AAAAA>
                0.888
            </AAAAA>
     </ImageResultList>
      <WaferList>
             <BBBB>
                1.999
             </BBBB>
       </WaferList>
    </ResultList>
</Results>


I need to depth value like 
"/Result/ImageResultList/AAAA"  =>  0.888
"/Result/WaferList/BBBB"      => 1.999
```

I am parsing an xml file in java.
When the data you want to parse has different depths
Is it possible to cut it with a separator, put it in an array, and get the value of the last Depth according to the tag contained in each array?